# How to fix configuration of ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having a problem getting my project to build. I get the message:

"A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> Cannot write to file 'C:\Workspace\depot\RM12\Mobile\AppSuite\Android\Working11\AppSuite\app\build\intermediates\data-binding\debug\bundle-bin' specified for property 'dataBindingArtifactOutputDir' as it is a directory"

This build issue won't occur for my first build after I clean the project, but if I try to build a second time I get this error. Which makes me do a clean and rebuild every time I need to run the project.

It occurs in some branches for me, while others don't seem to have this issue, and my coworkers have never seen this error. Which likely means this has something to do with my workspace.

I've done some research but haven't come across anything that has helped at all.

Please help me!!!

Comment: Did you solve this problem?